# How to import java files from folders in linux?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

In my linux, I have my java files that I coped from my windows eclipse project, and now I want to compile it in linux.

The folder structure is

```
PlutoMake.java
java-json.jar
Filter\ColorFilter.java
Filter\Darken.java
Filter\NoFilter.java
Filter\VividLight.java
```

The PlutoMake file has these imports and some others too like for json

```
import Filter.ColorFilter;
import Filter.Darken;
import Filter.NoFilter;
import Filter.VividLight;
```

But when I try to compile plutomake, it says

```
PlutoMake.java:12: package Filter does not exist
import Filter.ColorFilter;
```

I already use this to compile it:

```
javac -cp "java-json.jar" PlutoMake.java
```

and similarly for other ones too.

Does anyone know how to import it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `package Filter does not exist` error because the `Filter.*` classes are not present in the class path.

First compile the java files in side the folder `Filter` then compile the `PlutoMake.java` using `javac -cp "java-json.jar;." PlutoMake.java`

I'll advice to use some build tool like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) or [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/)

Comment: I did already compile the ones in the Filter folder but I still get this error. How can I have multiple class paths?

Comment: I got it to work with this `javac PlutoMake.java -cp java-json.jar Filter/*.java *.java`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question correctly. In eclipse just go to fil > Import > Existing Projects into Workspace
Select your project and import all your files. Then hit finish. 
Are they in the right subdirectories?

If you put /usr/share/'classpath', files defined with package Filter should be in /usr/share/Classes/Filter/
try setting java -classpath

[image]

Comment: I am doing this in linux.

Comment: Yeah in know. i also have linux (ubuntu as you can tell by the orange theme). Does that make a difference ?

Comment: I mean I just have a termainal through ftp.

Comment: O. What ftp client are you using ?

Comment: winscp. But its ok, I got it to work, i put the code I used in above comment.